# SharePoint Online: How to get my recently used sites?

Tags: sharepoint-online, microsoft-graph

In SharePoint Online, how can I get the list of my (e.g. the current user's) recently used sites as shown on the SharePoint start page (sharepoint.aspx)?

This question explicitly refers to sites, *not* documents or other single pieces of content. I need the site scope (or even better: groups). Preferably via Microsoft Graph.

Answer (score 0):

Enable the Reporting feature in SharePoint online in Site collection admin. Once you enable it, You will find Popularity Trends in Site settings and even in Document library ribbon you can find this icon. This will help you in getting details like site access reports, number of Hits, most popular item of a library etc.

Comment: I need this to be a report for the current user, e.g. **my** recently used sites. I don't think the aggregated usage reports can do that.